# How to compare a string with number

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a span id with textContent which have their own time(hour/minutes)

```
<div class="here">
<span class="time" >8 min</span>
</div>
<div class="here">
<span class="time" >22 min</span>
</div>
<div class="here">
<span class="time" >38 min</span>
</div>
<div class="here">
<span class="time" >1 hour</span>
</div>
<div class="here">
<span class="time" >1 day</span>
</div>
```

How can we show the span text whose time is less then 60 min, i don't want to show the text of span which contains 1 hour or 1 day any way to do that and yes string with number is necessary for my project.

Comment: Is your data hard coded as shown above or does it come from some API?

Comment: @bjbk coding mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll(".time")
els.forEach(el => {
  if (/(hour)|(day)/.test(el.textContent)) el.style.display = "none"
})
```

```html
<div class="here">
  <span class="time">8 min</span>
</div>
<div class="here">
  <span class="time">22 min</span>
</div>
<div class="here">
  <span class="time">38 min</span>
</div>
<div class="here">
  <span class="time">1 hour</span>
</div>
<div class="here">
  <span class="time">1 day</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me the logic behind this code?

Comment: It just selects the `span` elements, cycles through them checking with a regexp if the text contains the words `hour` or `day`, and in case, hides them.

Comment: Thanks with your explanation I got some ideas to try thanks again

Comment: Gets all elements with a class of ‘time’.  Then uses a regular expression to see if the text it contains has either the word ‘hour’ or the word ‘day. If it passes the test, then the display none style is added to the element

Comment: Thanks mate I tried using includes and it worked that way too

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(document.querySelectorAll(".time")[i].textContent.includes("min")){
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".time")[i].textContent);
    }
} 
}
```

This works too